# Mixin not working without any error - Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create a mixin for checking access token and some conditions. But it seem to be not working. Even i am using that `accesstoken` variable in `TimesheetListApiV2` which is inside `AccessTokenMixin`. How can i access that variable inside my view.

```
class AccessTokenMixin:

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            accesstoken=AccessToken.objects.get(
                        token=self.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').replace('Bearer ', '')
                    )

            if not accesstoken.application.company.company_tab_opts:
                return Response (
                    {
                        "status" : False,
                        "error" : "Tab Opts Error",
                        "error_message":"You are not allowed to access it.",
                    }
                )

            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response (
                {
                    "status" : False,
                    "error" : "Wrong Access Token",
                    "error_message":"You have provided wrong access token.",
                }
            )

class TimesheetListApiV2(AccessTokenMixin, APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        qs = User.objects.exclude(
                        Q(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True) |
                        Q(userprofile__user_company__company_is_deleted=True) 
                    ).filter(
                        Q(userprofile__user_company =accesstoken.application.company) 
                    )
        serializer = TimesheetListSerializer(qs, many=True)

        return Response (
                {
                    "status" : True,
                    "message":"Timesheet Retrieved Successfully.",
                    "result_count": qs.count(),
                    "api_name" : "TimesheetListApiV2",
                    "result": serializer.data,
                }
            )
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you don't have access to that accesstoken in the get method, you would get an error.

Comment: you can write custom permission for this, without using mixins

Comment: @c.grey how can i do it. Can you give me hint

Answer (score 0):

`accesstoken` variable is defined locally in the method `AccessTokenMixin.dispatch`, so it is not defined outside this method.

So your `TimesheetListApiV2.get` method should raise:

```
NameError: name 'accesstoken' is not defined
```

To fix that, simply replace `accesstoken` by `self.accesstoken`, to make this variable an attribute.

Comment: it is giving this error if accesstoken is wrong -    `assert renderer, ".accepted_renderer not set on Response"
AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response`